# Google Sheets Query cannot find some numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to use a `QUERY` function to get a maximum value of a range where value in another column equals to a specified value with

```
=QUERY(L$4:M,"select max(M) where L="&K1&" label max(M)''")
```

I tried `K1`=`99.75`, `109.725` or `114.7125` every values returns its `M` values until `L` goes above `114.7125` it returns `N/A`

I tried query in `L80:L100` with `119.7` which exists in row `88` also returns `N/A`

I tried making up values with `110.7225` `111.7200` `112.7175` `113.7150` `114.7125` `115.7100` `116.7075` `117.7050` `118.7025` `119.7000` it stops working with `115.7100`

I even tried `=QUERY(L$4:M,"select M where L='119.7'")` it returns `±` (the column header) and when I change to `=QUERY(L5:M...` it returns `N/A`

Here are `L4:M` data. All are actual values, not a function result. :

```
    | L            | M
----+--------------+-----------
  4 | Balance      |  ±
  5 |  99.75000000 |  -6023.86
  6 |  94.76250000 |  -1776.75
  7 |  89.77500000 |   2468.11
  8 |  85.60030690 |   6062.98
  9 |  84.78750000 |   6762.90
 10 |  79.80000000 |  11107.56
 11 |  74.81250000 |  15501.55
 12 |  77.11415433 |  13444.10
 13 |  79.80000000 |  11029.79
 14 |  75.81250000 |  14543.18
 15 |  74.81250000 |  15423.28
 16 |  75.43038050 |  14873.37
 17 |  79.80000000 |  10984.45
 18 |  84.78750000 |   6570.56
 19 |  89.77500000 |   2136.72
 20 |  99.75000000 |  -6789.91
 21 | 104.07461484 | -10461.51
 22 | 104.73750000 | -11024.30
 23 |  99.75000000 |  -6904.62
 24 | 104.73750000 | -11144.00
 25 |  99.75000000 |  -7099.14
 26 |  89.77500000 |   1190.09
 27 |  84.78750000 |   5434.45
 28 |  85.83562716 |   4543.36
 29 |  80.84812716 |   8787.72
 30 |  79.85062716 |   9670.51
 31 |  79.80000000 |   9714.86
 32 |  84.78750000 |   5002.17
 33 |  89.77500000 |    201.70
 34 |  94.76250000 |  -3783.31
 35 |  99.75000000 |  -7696.00
 36 |  94.76250000 |  -3950.39
 37 |  99.75000000 |  -7835.65
 38 | 104.73750000 |  11611.35
 39 |  99.75000000 |  -8264.74
 40 |  95.00454252 |  -4890.72
 41 |  94.76250000 |  -4718.63
 42 |  89.77500000 |  -1120.15
 43 |  90.74750000 |  -1838.83
 44 |  89.75000000 |  -1105.87
 45 |  84.76250000 |   2539.99
 46 |  79.77500000 |   6205.65
 47 |  89.77500000 |  -1284.35
 48 |  84.78750000 |   2162.01
 49 |  79.80000000 |   5708.12
 50 |  77.06182232 |   7696.04
 51 |  75.34427695 |   8942.98
 52 |  74.81250000 |   9329.05
 53 |  79.80000000 |   5543.54
 54 |  84.78750000 |   1828.35
 55 |  87.68533294 |   -234.88
 56 |  87.84530696 |   -348.78
 57 |  89.77500000 |  -1722.70
 58 |  94.76250000 |  -5208.96
 59 |  99.75000000 |  -8645.35
 60 | 104.73750000 |  11587.98
 61 | 109.72500000 |  14555.04
 62 | 104.73750000 |  11906.68
 63 |  99.75000000 |  -9205.95
 64 | 101.52622830 |  10092.29
 65 | 104.51872830 |  11585.55
 66 | 109.72500000 |  14183.48
 67 |  99.75000000 |  -9186.00
 68 |  89.77500000 |  -3689.77
 69 |  95.90606936 |  -6871.79
 70 |  99.75000000 |  -8866.79
 71 |  89.77500000 |  -3370.56
 72 |  79.80000000 |   2375.04
 73 |  69.82500000 |   8370.02
 74 |  74.81250000 |   5307.69
 75 |  79.80000000 |   2320.18
 76 |  74.81250000 |   5068.29
 77 |  69.82500000 |   8267.77
 78 |  74.81250000 |   4947.69
 79 |  79.80000000 |   1511.30
 80 |  89.77500000 |  -4363.98
 81 |  94.76250000 |  -6982.42
 82 |  99.75000000 |  -9725.05
 83 | 104.73750000 | -12093.61
 84 | 109.68750000 | -14269.09
 85 | 114.71250000 | -16416.54
 86 | 119.68750000 | -18540.99
 87 | 124.68750000 | -20641.54
 88 | 119.70000000 | -18890.88
 89 | 124.68750000 | -20781.14
 90 | 129.67500000 | -22471.90
 91 | 134.66250000 | -24112.79
 92 | 129.67500000 | -22711.30
 93 | 124.68750000 | -21210.06
 94 | 119.70000000 | -19634.01
 95 | 128.07469046 | -22064.35
 96 | 129.67500000 | -22531.64
 97 | 134.66250000 | -23978.76
 98 | 139.65003446 | -25444.60
 99 | 134.66253446 | -24092.99
100 | 139.65000000 | -25536.86
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Or is there any limitations on the `QUERY` function?

Comment: Try this query: `=QUERY(L4:M;"select M where L='"&K1&"' ORDER BY M DESC LIMIT 1 label M ''")`

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the order-limit technique. But your query still `N/A`. I even tried `=QUERY(L4:M,"select M where L='119.7'")` (fixed string) it returns `±` (the column header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I stumbled on [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721655/google-sheets-query-doesnt-display-all-values) I think I know the cause of my problem.

It should be about the data type of the cells. As the most of data is numbers, some of them are texts.

*The data was converted values from formula results. The conversion was made in scripts. Sorry for not posted in the original question.*

I think some of them are text because of my manual edits after the code runs.

All I have to do is change data formats for those cells. And to make sure, I did include the function `TEXT(L5, "0.00000000")` in data cells' and query formula.

So my query is now

```
=QUERY(L$4:M,"select max(M) where L="&TEXT(K1, "0.00000000")&" label max(M)''")
```

And I did change to use `order-limit` query as [@Kos's comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113685/google-sheets-query-cannot-find-some-numbers/113763#comment100599_113685). Now my final query is like this

```
=QUERY(L$4:M;"select M where L='"&TEXT(K1, "0.00000000")&"' order by M desc limit 1 label M ''")
```

I don't know which one is better. But I prefer the former one.

Answer (score 0):

> ... it stops working with `115.7100`

The formula

```
=QUERY(L$4:M,"select max(M) where L="&K1&" label max(M)''")
```

returns `N/A` because the L column doesn't contain `115.7100`.

> I even tried `=QUERY(L$4:M,"select M where L='119.7'")` it returns `±` (the column header)

The above formula returns only `±` because `'119.7'` is a text value and L column contains numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén I think it's about the data type of the cells. For `115.71` I made up values in another set of data and it's not in the posted one, sorry for the confusion.